# How to remove 0 in the power of a scientific notation in printf

Tags: linux, shell

In shell script, I want 23.343 to be output as 2.334E+1. When using `printf "%.3E\n" 23.343`, I got 2.334E+01. So how to remove that 0 by some trick in printf? And also is there a way to output the above number as 0.233E+02 by printf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) itself, you don't:

> **e, E**   The  double  argument  is  rounded and converted in the style [-]d.ddde±dd where there is one digit before the decimal-point character 
>    ... The exponent always contains at least two digits; if the value is zero, the exponent is 00.

But in e.g. Bash, you can remove the zero from the exponent manually:

```
$ x=$(printf "%.3E\n" 23.343)
$ $ echo "${x/E+0/E+}"
2.334E+1
```

(I missed the other part of the question.)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to output the number as 0.233E+02?

Comment: @user6948979, oh, I misread, I only noticed the exponent part. The same manual says that there's always one digit before the decimal point... and fixing that would be a bit more work...